# is there plugin Predefined users to login wordpress front end only

Tags: wordpress

I want to pre-define user list who can allow to enter site front end.is there any plugin for that in wordpress.So that the specified members can login in to the front website.not admin panel

Comment: Yes, Theme My Login

Comment: only for front-end login not for admin panel

Comment: this plugin allow user to login in frontend instead of backend

Answer (score 0):

Below plugin is useful for make user login access for front end.you can extend plugin as plugin use custom table for save user detail in DB.

[Front-End Only Users](https://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-only-users/)

Answer (score 0):

[User registration & user profile - Profile Builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/) plugin is useful to make user login access for front end.